# Undo batch process

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

Is there a way to undo batch processes/revert to how my categories and articles were set up before a batch process? I had a fairly intricate hierarchy of categories established and when I went to copy them over the hierarchy was lost.

Comment: With no idea what the "batch process" was, it's highly unlikely that there's a "revert" button - I hope you have a backup.

Comment: Need clarification of the batch process, assuming on categories but not sure and what specifically what command did you batch?  Although, this is usually not something easily reversed.  Do you have a development or staging environment with the old hierarchy still intact?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have made a backup of your website, or have a previous copy of your database with the old category structure, I'm afraid the answer is NO (at least as far as I know). There's no way to undo the batch process.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, everyone. I was hoping to simply be able to copy my existing categories/articles over to another category, but clearly it isn't that easy. I'll be more careful with what I batch process from now on.